# Retrieve attribute from Object path like data.#0.elements.#0.name"

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm using Polymer to deep-watch changes in an JS object. The event gives me an object path specifying the attribute that changed in the format `data.#0.element.#0.name"`.

How can I turn this programmatically into `data[0].elements[0].name` so I can access it again?

I've never stumbled upon such paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.get("data.#0.element.#0.name", this)` should do what you want.
See also https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/master/src/standard/notify-path.html#L235

Comment: Yes, it works. What if I wanted to get the parent object of the name attribute?

Comment: You mean `"data.#0.element.#0"`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Currently I do this with a regex `replace(/.[^.]+$/,"")`